# Why did apt not prompt me to confirm installing dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Usually, installing a package with dependencies that aren't currently installed [will make apt confirm whether this is desired](https://superuser.com/a/287357/717164) before proceeding to install:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide libhyphen0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libnautilus-extension1a libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
  libyelp0 yelp yelp-xsl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide libhyphen0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libnautilus-extension1a libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libyelp0 yelp yelp-xsl
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

However, a few minutes ago, I ran exactly the same command, and apt installed gnome-terminal and its dependencies without asking:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide libhyphen0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libnautilus-extension1a libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2
  libyelp0 yelp yelp-xsl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide libhyphen0 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libnautilus-extension1a libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2 libyelp0 yelp yelp-xsl
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main armhf libnautilus-extension1a armhf 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu6 [51.9 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf gnome-terminal-data all 3.18.3-1ubuntu1 [41.0 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf gnome-terminal armhf 3.18.3-1ubuntu1 [148 kB]
...
```

Why did apt do this?

Comment: Most of those are connected to yelp it seems, which is only a recommend. These will usually be installed, but can be set not to I think? Have you changed anything with /etc/apt/apt.conf or similar?

Comment: @Guy Not that I remember. (It's an Ubuntu 16.04 chroot using [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton), so I guess it's possible that that did some extra configuration automatically? otoh I think the setting in question is `APT::Install-Recommends`, and I can't find anything related to that in /etc/apt.)